# Why does the Earth's axial tilt create an east-west variation in the analemma?

Tags: orbit, earth

I've been reading about the Earth's analemma from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma), and I am having trouble visualizing one component. Let's build up to my question.

1. If the Earth had a circular orbit and no axial tilt, the analemma would be a dot.
2. If the Earth had an eccentric orbit and no axial tilt, the analemma would be a east-west line.
3. If the Earth had a circular orbit and axial tilt, the analemma would be symmetric figure eight.

My question:  In situation 3, I understand the north-south variation of the symmetric analemma, but I don't understand why there would be symmetric east-west variation.

Why does the Earth's axial tilt create an east-west variation in the analemma?

Comment: Related: [Effect of the obliquity of the ecliptic / tilt of the Earth on the equation of time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25567/effect-of-the-obliquity-of-the-ecliptic-tilt-of-the-earth-on-the-equation-of-t)

Comment: There's a detailed explanation in this document [The Analemma for  
Latitudinally-Challenged People](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/analemma.pdf).

Comment: The east-west variation in the analemma **is** the equation of time, making this a duplicate of the previously cited linked question.